# Specifying view function in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm practicing in Django and I want to know how requests and view mechanisms work correct in Django.

I started an app called ghcrawler in my django project. I designed like it has to send responses that recevied from `localhost/ghcrawler` and `localhost/ghcrawler/results`

So this is the `urls.py` in ghcrawler/ app folder.

```
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import main_view, results_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('', main_view.as_view() , name='ghcrawler'),
    path('ghresults', results_view.as_view(), name='getresults')
]
```

`localhost/grcrawler` page works well as expected. I just want to wire the requests coming to `localhost/ghcrawler/results` to `getresults()` function in `results_view` class defined in `views.py`, however it doesn't even write the 'h1' to the console

`ghcrawler/views.py`:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.shortcuts import render
from django import forms
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .github_requester import search_user

class main_view(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'ghcrawler.html'

    # Handle the post request received from /ghcrawler/
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            user = search_user(request.POST.get("username", ""))
            
            if user == None:
                print("User not found.")

            else: 
                print(user)
            return HttpResponse("OK")

class results_view(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'ghresults.html'

    def getresults(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print('h1')
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than `localhost/ghcrawler/results` you mapped `localhost/ghcrawler/ghresults` to your view.

the rigth code would be:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', main_view.as_view() , name='ghcrawler'),
    path('results', results_view.as_view(), name='ghresults')
]
```

the firs argument in `path`is the actual path

the secont argumen is the view

the third argument `name` is optional and used for addressing your view independant of your path

```py
class results_view(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'ghresults.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print('h1')
```